# Differences between inductor and electromagnet?

Tags: inductor

This seems like a very stupid question but I have to clear my doubts.

When we connect an inductor of like 6-7 turns to a DC battery, the battery gets shorted out. But when we make an electromagnet of like 50-60 turns, and connect it to a battery, it works fine. Is it because in the case of electromagnets, the resistance is high due to a larger number of turns?

Also, when we disconnect the inductor from the DC source, its magnetic field collapses and a high surge of current is produced. So for that, we connect a diode (flyback diode) across it. Basically an electromagnet is nothing but an inductor with many turns. But why is this diode not used when we make an electromagnet?

Even on YouTube, all the electromagnet DIY projects are made without the diode. They just simply connect and disconnect their electromagnets without getting any minor shocks. Why is this?

Comment: About those DIY project, do you see any fragile electronic components which can be damaged by inductive kickback connected with the electromagnet?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it because in the case of electromagnets, the resisitance is high
>   due to more number of turns?

6 turns or 60 turns will likely have quite a low resistance unless you are using really microscopically thin copper or a big diameter of solenoid or electromagnet but yes, the more DC resistance it has the better a DC supply rail survives without going into current limit.

> Also, when we disconnect the inductor from the DC source, its magnetic
>   field collapses and a high surge of current is produced.

No, a surge of voltage is produced in a failing attempt (by the inductor) to maintain the current that was previously flowing before it was disconnected.

> But why this diode is not used when we make an electromagnet?

A diode is used for an electromagnet AND a solenoid if the circuit is being controlled by a semiconductor i.e. a transistor. Sometimes it's omitted because a secondary winding can clamp the kick-back voltage to a level that protects the transistor.

If the coil isn't controlled with a transistor a diode may be used to prevent arcing across the switching contact and it can also restrict EMI from interfering with other electronics. In the main, a diode is used.

> Even on YouTube, all the electromagnet DIY projects are made without
>   the diode. They just simply connect and disconnect their
>   electromagnets without getting any minor shocks. Why is this?

You can get a small electric shock but it's usually barely noticeable in a lot of experiments - as you disconnect the contacting wires, the spark forms at the gap and is usually over in microseconds.

However, don't rely on YouTube for setting good examples because there are types of solenoids that can give quite a sizable jolt if not handled correctly.

Comment: In one vid a guy made a 1T electromagnet, the spark from the spark gap lit up the room when he shut it off.

Answer (score -1):

A flyback diode should, I think, be used with an electro magnet because the collapse of the mag field will cause reverse current that can damage the driving side. The diode presents a short path that skips the control circuit. Regardless of if I’m wrong, the diode shouldn’t hurt anything.

Re your comment about 5 or 6 vs 60 turns.

Resistance doesn’t really play into it significantly. What does play in is both the number of turns and the ferrite core. Much of the current goes into building the magnetic field. More turns and a better core means stronger field means less current.

While the circuit looks shorted in the real plane, much of it is going to the imaginary plane to build the mag field.

Of course all of this is from my ancient electro mag courses so I might be wrong.

Comment: Also: “Even in Youtube” made me laugh. YouTube is full of just as much, if not more, wrong stuff than right.

Comment: Can you explain how the current reverses? I was always taught that the inductor tries to maintain current in the same direction and it does this by reversing its terminal voltage. Also, a higher permeability core doesn’t alter the magnetic field strength (H), it just allows the lines of magnetic field to concentrate in the core and slightly increases the useful flux density produced by a solenoid or electromagnet.

Comment: @Andyaka as I said, my electro mag courses were eons ago. From what I remember when the mag field collapses when the forward voltage is dropped the change in the field induces a reverse voltage this a reverse current through the coil.

Comment: @Andyaka I hit send too soon. Anyway, I always pictured it as a flow of current pushing against a valve that is spring loaded. The voltage being the pressure that makes the current flow. When the voltage goes to zero the valve slams shut pushing the water in the reverse direction. But like I said, it was a long time ago. Thx for clarification on the influence of the core. I’m gonna hook some inductors up to my scope tonight to see what is really happening. Party party!!

Comment: The voltage reverses to keep the (same) current flowing in the same direction through the coil i.e. it tries to hold onto the energy stored in the magnetic field. Do your tests and you'll see.

Comment: @Andyaka I don’t understand how a voltage reversal can serve to keep the current flowing on the same direction. Can you explain?  Maybe I’m picturing it wrong. Tests are in order.

Comment: @Andyaka nvm.  I got it now.  Its a reverse voltage as seen by the source but its a forward voltage as seen by the inductor.  This actually fits with my plumbing visualization.  Anyway, thx